# Two way binding of select input in a directive not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I've created a directive for a select input to select a userId. The model binds from the directive to the rest of the view. However, when I set the id from the controller it doesn't seem to bind to select input in the directive.

Controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  // set userId to willem's Id
  $scope.userId = 3;
});
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('selectUser', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.users = [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": 'Tupac'
      }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": 'Biggie'
      }, {
        "id": 3,
        "name": 'Willem'
      }];
      },
    templateUrl: 'directive.html'
  };
});
```

index.html

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    users:
  <select-user ng-model="userId"></select-user>

  userId = {{userId}}
  </body>
```

directive.html

```
<select class='form-control focus' ng-model="ngModel">
    <option value="">all users</option>
// doesn't bind from the controller. Supposed to show willem, instead of all users to start with.
    <option ng-Repeat="user in users" value="{{user.id}}">{{user.name}}</option> 
</select>
```

Working example on: http://plnkr.co/edit/c7eyoB

Comment: `ng-Repeat` to `ng-repeat` r should be small case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `ngOptions` :

```
<select class='form-control focus' ng-model="ngModel" ng-options="user.id as user.name for user in users">
    <option value="">all users</option>
</select>
```

Then the binding will work. **See [updated plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/SIqIrGWBxLDtnJAdZvwM?p=preview)**

---

**Edit, concerning the following question in comment :**

> could you please explain, why it is not working with ng-repeat?

You can achieve the same visual result with :

```
<select class='form-control focus' ng-model="ngModel">
  <option value="">all users</option>
  <option ng-repeat="user in users" value="{{user.id}}" ng-selected="user.id === ngModel">{{user.name}}</option>
</select>
```

I.e. we added `ng-selected="user.id === ngModel"`.

But this has some drawbacks. First, you are creating unneeded isolated scopes. And also, the values bound to the options are strings, i.e. you will actually select `'1'`, `'2'` or `'3'` instead of `1`, `2` or `3`.

Comment: could you please explain, why it is not working with ng-repeat?

Comment: @pankajparkar, you could do that with `<option ng-repeat="...">` but then you would have to use `ng-selected="user.id === ngModel"`. Though, using ng-options is still a better option, because you don't create isolated scopes.

Comment: that means isolated scopes are breaking the binding

Comment: I mean your point is right but why making `$scope.userId = '3';` inside controller doesn't work & why we need `ng-selected` any reasons..just asking..curious to know that.Thanks

Comment: @pankajparkar I do think that is because of the isolated scopes. Manipulating the same data type as option values, i.e. strings will be enough if you hardcode the options : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/dofk699m/). But now with `ng-repeat`-ed options, you lose the binding : [second fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/r60kconz/)

Comment: There must be some issue with angular at this point..Or are missing somthing silly

Comment: Appretiated your efforts for more clarification +1 ..but still not clear on point..