# Why ng-model resets selected option?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Select list is generated by php in page. When I added `ng-model` to this select it resets selected default option.

```
<select name="day" ng-model="day" class="form-control" ng-required="true" required="required">
<option value="22" selected="selected">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
</select>
```

How fix it?

Comment: `ng-model` *is* what sets the value of input controls. It works both ways - it is set by the user interacting with the control, and by changing `ng-model`, the control reacts.

Comment: If you will set value which u want to set as default then set value from controller day variable

Comment: Does not work, you can check

Comment: What do you have in `$scope.day` ?

Comment: I have $scope.day = 0;

Comment: Then put `$scope.day = '22';` instead

Comment: Why put 22 when 22 is current day that will change on next day

Comment: Because you didn't explained in your question that you want to select the current day... You can put `$scope.day = '' + (new Date()).getDate()`. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/7949x1eg/2/). That will get you the current day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `var currentDay = '' + (new Date()).getDate();`

You should use `ng-options` and set `$scope.day = currentDay;` for selecting the current day.

Just discussed about `ng-options` vs repeating options **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29195601/3120193)**

In general, `ng-options` is a better option (no pun) over `<option ng-repeat='...'>`, because it is far more flexible.

---

If you don't want to use `ng-options`, put `$scope.day = currentDay;` in your scope and remove `selected="selected"` as the binding will be done between `$scope.day` and the values of the options. **See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/7949x1eg/2/)**

***Template:***

```
<select name="day" ng-model="day" class="form-control" ng-required="true" required="required">
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
</select>
```

***Controller:***

```
$scope.day = currentDay; // Get the current day of month as a string.
```

Comment: I ca not use `ng-options` my selcet list must be created by PHP

Comment: How can "my select list must be created by PHP" prevent you from using `ng-options` ?

Comment: if it's created by PHP, maybe consider use ajax call and insert it to the $scope, as an object that contains the days.

Answer (score 1):

there is a simple solution for this,

if you create `select` from the backend, put `ng-init` as below,

```
<select name="day" ng-model="day" ng-init="day=22"...
```

`ng-init="day=22"` initialize `day` model to the selected value `(22)`.

here is [the punker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oySlW0fDYcy9oxYx1lh4?p=preview)

---

**OR**

use a angularjs controller function to initialize the scope variable and its a best practice.

For ex: ,

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="initializeScopeVariables(22)">
```

In controller,

```
$scope.initializeScopeVariables = function(initSelectedVal) {
   $scope.day = initSelectedVal;
};
```

here is [the Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/i9HEkz6k42VMVb7mrZfs?p=preview)